# Is there a way to select from a MySql column using the IN, where a column has multiple words?

Tags: php, mysql

I am querying a MySQL table, and want it only to output items that match the word but can have other words as well. I am sort of looking for the equivalence of in MySql.

```
strpos ( string $haystack , string $needle)
```

[PHP myAdmin TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8uI9.png)  Here is an image of my phpMyAdmin table. I am trying to search the table if the rightmost column, the `archetype` column. I am trying to find all results that match one word like Voltron, but the problem is that for example item #11, also has the word 'Keyword' in that column so it won't show.

[Image I'm Searching By](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUdaE.png) This is an example of what I want to search by. The last column, the archetype column is the variable. I want to query MySQL for all items that were Archetype like Tribal, or like Voltron, but can contain other 'Archetypes' as well.
When I query by this card, item number 3,9,10,11, and 15 should be outputted.

```
$aType = explode(" ", $aType);
    $array_in_strings = join(", ",$aType); 
      //This Decides the Cards.  
      $query_all_items = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `edh__cardDatabase` WHERE `name` NOT LIKE '$name' AND (`archetype`) IN ('$array_in_strings') ORDER BY `name` ASC;");
```

And finally, this is what I have as the code.

Comment: The MySQL function equivalent to PHP's `strpos()` would be [LOCATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate).

Comment: If a question under these tags contains the words `here is an image of my table`, it tends to get down- and close- voted. Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-queryyour

Answer (score 0):

Implode your words list to CSV string then use a query similar to

```sql
SELECT *
FROM {tablename}
WHERE FIND_IN_SET({columnname}, 'CSV,words,list')
  AND {another conditions}
```

Pay attention - if you put a space between a comma and the next word then this space will be treated as a part of a word. I.e. `'word'` will be found in `'this,is,a,word'` but not found in `'this, is, a, word'`.